# whether to use list or an array for storing the values of red green and blue channels - python opencv

Tags: python, arrays, list, opencv, numpy

I am using list for storing the channels values, and i tried this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os,glob
resizelist = list()
B_mean = list()
G_mean = list()
R_mean = list()
path = 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\dataset1'
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.jpg')):
   imge = cv2.imread(infile)
   arr1 = np.array(imge)
   re_img = cv2.resize(imge,(200,200))
   resizelist.append(re_img)
   blue, green, red = cv2.split(re_img)
   total = re_img.size
   B = sum(blue) / total
   G = sum(green) / total
   R = sum(red) / total
   B_mean.append(B)
   G_mean.append(G)
   R_mean.append(R)
main_list = [[],[],[]]
main_list[0] = B_mean
main_list[1] = G_mean
main_list[2] = R_mean
print main_list
```

Instead of the values, it is displaying only zeros. Is there anything wrong with the code? As i'm going to calculate entropy, contrast and homogeneity, and going to store all these values in a single list/array.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: Where is your code buddy...?

Comment: Don't use list. Use np.array.

Comment: is it possible for you to show me a snipped of code which shows appending the values in list to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array will be a good option to use and it will be more intuitive for you to access that values from it later.

Comment: is it possible for you to show me a snipped of code which shows appending the values in list to an array? that will help me alot.